# Display AV1 Video in HTML Player

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I want to stream a video encoded with rav1e to a browser. rav1e will package the video in ivf packets.

When I embed a video file inside html, the player does not work properly:

```html
...
<video controls>
    <source src="myvideo.ivf" type="video/mp4; codecs=av01" />
</video>
...
```

Controls are showing, but the video is not loaded properly:

[image]

I assume this is due to the unexpected ivf-package format. Is there a way to display the video stream without repackaging it?

Comment: Not a fix but please note that the [<source>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-source-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: I see, but why?

Comment: Why are you using it? It is unspecified. Does nothing. Has no meaning and browsers ignore it.

Comment: I copy and pasted the html :)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/gpac/gpac offers a quick way to repackage the video file into *.mp4: `MP4Box -add myvideo.ivf myvideo.mp4`
Optimally I would not need that, so I will leave the question open for now